# Overriding the output for the primary navigation links

Tags: 7, theming

Is there another way the primary navigation is supposed to printed out besides how it is done in the core system template?

```
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu));`
```

None of the changes I made via the `theme_menu_link()` function are recognized when the links are printed this way. Are they only seen if I manually put the primary links *block* into a region?

Which is the function that I could use to override the primary links when printed out this way? Everything I have with `theme_menu_link()` does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax (two underscores) means that it first looks for a `theme_links__system_main_menu()`theme function and then falls back to `theme_links()` if that doesn't exist.

So to override only the main menu, create the following theme function for your theme: `yourtheme_links__system_main_menu()`.